# Global thread local object for Rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some Python frameworks such as Flask, Pyramid and Pylons provide a `g` object, a thread-local global object that persists for the request.  It's very useful, as it can contain the current user as initialized in a `before_request` hook, etc.

Since RoR does not provide such an object, what is the equivalent "Ruby-esque" way to do the same thing?

```
before_request hook initializes some variables on g
-> routing
controller accesses variables initialized in before_request
```

Comment: No, they don't. Django, in particular, specifically avoids any thread-local request objects.

Comment: @DanielRoseman well the ones I mentioned do. And I feel like it's very convenient. Although I would be interested as to why Django avoids thread-local request objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ruby on Rails, you should use an instance variable (instance varialbes start with an `@`, for example `@user`) which is available in the controller and in the view, and only for the current request.

Comment: does rails provide some sort of `before_request` hook?

Comment: @Aristides yes, it's called `before_action` in Rails 4, and `before_filter` in older versions. See how it works here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: So `@variable` set in `before_action` would be available to the controller that eventually routes it, y/n?